# C++: Swap Rows For A Matrix: Using a SINGLE DIMENSION Array

Tags: c++

Dear nice and smart people, would you mind sharing with me why my code is unable to swap rows for a matrix please? When I run the code, both rows become the same, omg.

entries[i] is the dynamic array storing the elements in the matrix.
Elements are stored row by row, from left to right. 
i.e. in a 3X3 matrix, entries[2] is 3rd element on the 1st row, 
entries[3] is 1st element on the 2nd row

```
n = number of rows in matrix
m = number of columns in matrix

void Matrix::SwapRows(int i, int j) {
    double* temp;
    temp = new double[n * m];
    double* temp2;
    temp2 = new double[n * m];
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= m; b++) {
            if (a == i) {
                temp[(j - 1) * m + b - 1] = entries[(j - 1) * m + b - 1];
                entries[(a - 1) * m + b - 1] = temp[(j - 1) * m + b - 1];
            }
            if (a == j) {
                temp2[(i - 1) * m + b - 1] = entries[(i - 1) * m + b - 1];
                entries[(a - 1) * m + b - 1] = temp2[(i - 1) * m + b - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    delete temp;
    delete temp2;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You have two memory leaks in your function. Also, `a = i` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: `if (a = i)` and `if (a = j) ` assigns to `a`. You probably want `if (a == i)` and `if (a == j) `

Comment: You may like [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: changed from = to ==, still cannot. But thanx for spotting that mistake!

Comment: If you are swapping rows why `temp = new double[n * m];` is `n*m`

Answer (score 0):

THanx to Jesper Juhl, swap does the trick. Correct method is as per below. Thank you Jesper!

```
void Matrix::SwapRows(int i, int j) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= m; b++) {
            if (a == i) {
                swap (entries[(a - 1) * m + b - 1], entries[(j - 1) * m + b - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```